# Did I successfully change a forbidden http header?

Tags: node.js, http

According to this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name, I am not supposed to be able to change a forbidden http header programatically. A forbidden header such as 'Origin', for example.

I have this Node.JS code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    console.log('entry point');
    const res2 = request.post({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/test',
      headers: {'Origin': "Lol"}
    });
    console.log({res2: res2});
    res.status(200).json({res2: res2});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

You can see that I definitely set the 'Origin' header to a 'Lol' value.

So my expectations are: an error, another value set by default by my middleware or something but in any case, I shoudln't get the 'lol' value when I print the req object (right?).

Actual output:

```
{ 
   "res2":{ 
      "uri":{ 
         "protocol":"http:",
         "slashes":true,
         "auth":null,
         "host":"localhost:3000",
         "port":"3000",
         "hostname":"localhost",
         "hash":null,
         "search":null,
         "query":null,
         "pathname":"/test",
         "path":"/test",
         "href":"http://localhost:3000/test"
      },
      "method":"POST",
      "headers":{ 
         "Origin":"Lol",
         "host":"localhost:3000"
      }
   }
}
```

You can see that the value is 'Lol', as NOT expected.

So I am definitely missing something. Do you IT guys have any idea of what it could be?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is this the output from the `console.log` or what the endpoint at `ttp://localhost:3000/test` receives?

Comment: You are sending the request, in this case, node is the user agent when you make the `request.post`. You are not changing anything from the web browser. What you linked specifically says the user agent has control over the headers.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc Of course! It makes total sense now, my Node.JS is the user agent! Sorry I'm not at ease with web development, AT ALL. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @FelixKling It is what the endpoint receives at /test, yes.

Comment: @Yves-MarieIp not for the initial request to `/` though, only the request that it sends. The originator of the request is typically the "user-agent"

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc Yeah I had this one :) But still nice to precise it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Adam Leblanc said in the comments: my NodeJS app is the 'user-agent' sending the request, meaning it's the 'owner'. So it can easily value the 'Origin' header with anything.

That was a noob question, but I believe that we all start as newbs. Thanks for your answser Adam.